# Display a sorted array of objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, window

I have an Array of Objects.

```
let myArray = [
    {name: "name1", image: "image1"},
    {name: "name2", image: "image2"},
    {name: "name3", image: "image3"},
    {name: "name4", image: "image4"},
    {name: "name5", image: "image5"},
];
```

I have displayed every object in this array using the following code:

```
function displayObjects(objectsDisplayed) {
    for (let i of myArray) {
        // Code to display every object in the array
        document.getElementById('div-to-hold-data').appendChild('code');
    }
}
```

This has worked as expected.

I have also created multiple sort buttons to sort the array by different types of values. When I logged the results of this sort to the console, this worked as expected.

```
function sortProducts(value) {
  let sortOrder = 1;
  if(value[0] === "-") {
    sortOrder = -1;
    value = value.substr(1);
  }
  return function (a, b) {
    let result = (a[value] < b[value]) ? -1 : (a[value] > b[value]) ? 1:0;
    return result * sortOrder;
  }
}



let sortBy = document.getElementById("sort-by");
function sortChange() {
  let sortByValue = sortBy.value;
  if (sortByValue === "category1") {
    myArray.sort(sortProducts("name"));
    console.log(objectsDisplayed);
  } else if (sortByValue === "name-decending") {
    myArray.sort(sortProducts("image"));
    console.log(objectsDisplayed);
  }
  displayObjects(objectsDisplayed);
}

sortBy.onchange = function() {
  sortChange();
}
```

The above code logs the correctly sorted array to the console. However, the objects displayed to the window remain the same.

I now want to clear the window and then display the new sorted array to the window, instead of the console. How could I do this.

Comment: Just keep object references to the HTML elements you create, and then remove and re-insert them in the correct order

Comment: You never use `objectsDisplayed` in your function

Comment: Just a note, if you are comparing two strings, use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead of ternary operators.