# Sort content in a div JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have created an Array of Objects.

```
let products = [
{name: "Name 3"},
{name: "Name 2"},
{name: "Name 1"},
{name: "Name 4"},
{name: "Name 5"}]
```

I have added all of the objects in this Array to the page using a for loop.

```
for (i in products) {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.innerText = i;
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(card);
}
```

I have also created multiple sort buttons for this Array. If I click one of these buttons, the products should be sorted. For example, if I click a button to sort the products by name, the products should be reordered and shown in ascending order of their name.

When I log the sorted array to the console, it works as expected. However, the sorted Array does not show up on screen but the original array instead remains on screen. Why is this and how could I cause the sorted array to show up on screen.

Comment: Most likely you're not actually setting the `textContent` of any of the div elements after sorting the array.

Comment: You've already asked this didn't you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75643954/display-a-sorted-array-of-objects-javascript

Comment: You should declare your `i` variable in the loop, and the loop should be `for...of` rather than `for...in` (which is used for iterating over objects). Also shouldn't you be adding just the value of the name property rather than the whole object as you appear to be doing at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you are sorting the array how you want it. You should just do this to replace the html.

```
$('#myDiv').html('');

for (i in sortedProducts) {
    let card = document.createElement("div");
    card.innerText = i;
    document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(card);
}
```